# Client does not interact with the server java (Socket)-

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, client-server

Is a client application that should create an interface and connect to the server which then connects to db to run queries.
I can't understand why the client doesn't connect to the server.
The server works, while the client gives me the NullPointerException error.

Code server:

```
public class ServerLab  extends Thread{


   private Socket socket;
   private BufferedReader in;
   private PrintWriter out;
   public ServerLab(Socket socket) throws IOException {
       this.socket = socket;
       this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
       this.out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
       start();

   }

   public void run() {
       
       try {
           while (true) {
               String c =in.readLine();
               System.out.println(c);
           }
       }catch(IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       
       
   }
}
```

code client:

```
public class RegCentV extends Thread{

   JFrame frame;
   private JTextField cap;
   private JTextField sigla;
   private JTextField comune;
   private JTextField nome;
   private JTextField indirizzo;
   private JComboBox comboBox_1,comboBox;
   private String ind,t;
   int PORT = 6060;
   private Socket socket;
   private BufferedReader in;
   private PrintWriter out;

   /**
    * Launch the application.
    */
   public RegCentV(InetAddress add) throws IOException {
       this.socket = new Socket("192.168.1.17", 6060);
       this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
       this.out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
       start();
   }
   public void run() {
       try {
           out.println("Hello server");
           RegCentV window = new RegCentV();
           window.frame.setVisible(true);
           
           
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   /**
    * Create the application.
    */
   public RegCentV() {
       initialize();
   }

   /**
    * Initialize the contents of the frame.
    */
   private void initialize() {
       frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setBounds(100, 100, 579, 325);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       
       JLabel lblNewLabel_5 = new JLabel("Nome Centro Vaccinale");
       lblNewLabel_5.setBounds(10, 64, 163, 14);
       
       nome = new JTextField();
       nome.setBounds(183, 61, 96, 20);
       nome.setColumns(10);
       
       JLabel lblNewLabel_4 = new JLabel("Indirizzo");
       lblNewLabel_4.setBounds(289, 64, 71, 14);
       
       String[] addres = { "Via", "V.le", "Piazza" };
       JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox(addres);
       comboBox_1.setBounds(382, 61, 57, 20);
       
       JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("Comune");
       lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(10, 105, 136, 14);
       
       comune = new JTextField();
       comune.setBounds(183, 102, 96, 20);
       comune.setColumns(10);
       
       JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Sigla Provincia");
       lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(289, 105, 91, 14);
       
       sigla = new JTextField();
       sigla.setBounds(380, 102, 96, 20);
       sigla.setColumns(10);
       
       JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("CAP");
       lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 152, 132, 14);
       
       cap = new JTextField();
       cap.setBounds(183, 149, 96, 20);
       cap.setColumns(10);
       
       JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Tipologia");
       lblNewLabel.setBounds(286, 152, 74, 14);
       
       String[] tipe = { "Ospedaliero", "Hub", "Aziendale" };
       JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(tipe);
       comboBox.setBounds(382, 149, 85, 20);
       
       frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
       frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_5);
       frame.getContentPane().add(nome);
       frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_4);
       frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox_1);
       
       indirizzo = new JTextField();
       indirizzo.setBounds(447, 61, 96, 20);
       frame.getContentPane().add(indirizzo);
       indirizzo.setColumns(10);
       frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_3);
       frame.getContentPane().add(comune);
       frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2);
       frame.getContentPane().add(sigla);
       frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);
       frame.getContentPane().add(cap);
       frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
       frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
       
       JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("SALVA");
       btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
           @Override
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
               ind = comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().toString();
               t =  comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
               registraCentroVaccinale();
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Elemento salvato");
               IntSeconda nuovaPage=new IntSeconda();
               nuovaPage.frame.setVisible(true);
               RegCentV.this.frame.dispose();
           }
       });
       btnNewButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
       btnNewButton.setBounds(343, 225, 96, 23);
       frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
       
       JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("INDIETRO");
       btnNewButton_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
           @Override
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
               IntSeconda nuovaPage=new IntSeconda();
               nuovaPage.frame.setVisible(true);
               RegCentV.this.frame.dispose();
           }
       });
       btnNewButton_1.setBackground(Color.RED);
       btnNewButton_1.setBounds(170, 225, 96, 23);
       frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);
       
       JLabel lblNewLabel_6 = new JLabel("REGISTRAZIONE CENTRO VACCINALE");
       lblNewLabel_6.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
       lblNewLabel_6.setBounds(156, 11, 326, 39);
       frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_6);
       
   }
}
```

Main Client:

```
public class Main_Op {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       RegCentV client = new RegCentV();
       client.start();
   }

}
```

can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the ServerSocket? If you run please put the code which you run the server and the exception stack trace here.

Answer (score 0):

when you start Main_Op , you start the thread you created using the default constructor.

```
public class Main_Op {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    RegCentV client = new RegCentV();
    client.start();
}

// the default constructor you call does not set this.in, this.out or this.socket
// calls initialize for gui fields but doesn't set in, out or socket
public RegCentV() {
   initialize();
}
```

Yet when you run the client, the run method looks like this:

```
public void run() {
   try {
       out.println("Hello server");
       RegCentV window = new RegCentV();
       window.frame.setVisible(true);
       
       
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

}

You are using out but out is null at this point.
if you use the other constructor you would have an out to use. But there is a problem there:

```
// 
public RegCentV(InetAddress add) throws IOException {
   this.socket = new Socket("192.168.1.17", 6060);
   this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
   this.out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
   start();
}
```

the other constructor starts the thread it just finished creating. (worse, if you subclass this constructor it may start it before it is done creating.)

I think that start() really doesn't belong there, but I admit this isn't the question you are asking. Just some additional advice.

Basically: you have multiple constructors but only 1 constructor does it's job. (a constructor's job is to bring the object into a stable/usable state.) You should probably merge both constructors as 1 is doing network and the other is doing gui. Or split them into 2 different classes and have each perform only their own job. (gui can own a network-client object to use/perform calls on. possibly register itself as a listener as well)